# Cannot use .replace() on all elements contain same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am using the method below to replace all `<p>` tags' comma to hash

```
var node = document.getElementByClassName('discovereedKeywords');
node.innerHTML = node.innerHTML.replace(/,/g, '#');
```

and in reality those `<p>` tags are actually generate by a for loop, but my method only change the first `<p>`tag it found therefore i tried something like below

Consider the html looks like this

```
 <p class="discovereedKeywords"> apple,banana,oranger</p>

 <p class="discovereedKeywords"> apple,oranger,oranger</p>

 <p class="discovereedKeywords"> kiwi,melon,pinapple</p>
```

Javascript

```
for (var i=0; i <data.result.data.length; i++){
    var node[i] = document.getElementByClassName('discovereedKeywords');
    node[i].innerHTML = node.innerHTML.replace(/,/g, '#');
}
```

Comment: you should use `innerText` instead of `innerHTML`

Comment: If you already include jQuery as suggested by your question's tags, then use it... BTW, you should learn how to debug javascript before going forward

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('p').text(function(_, txt){
   return txt.replace(/,/g, '#');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="discovereedKeywords"> apple,banana,oranger</p>

 <p class="discovereedKeywords"> apple,oranger,oranger</p>

 <p class="discovereedKeywords"> kiwi,melon,pinapple</p>
```

In jQuery, you can use `text()` method:

```
$('p').text(function(_, txt){
   return txt.replace(/,/g, '#');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work, problem is that `document.getElementsByClassName` returns DOM array
But you are using `document.getElementByClassName` which is not valid
Simply there is no `document.getElementByClassName`, notice the **s** symbol

```
var nodes = document.getElementsByClassName('discovereedKeywords');
//this converts DOM array to plain JS Array
[].slice.call(nodes).forEach(function(node){
    node.innerHTML = node.innerHTML.replace(/,/g, '#');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You were close! First of all, it's `getElementsByClassName`, plural. Second, if you want to get an *i*-th element, use the i on the array, not on the variable.

Here's [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fsk7jx7n/).

```
for (var i = 0; i < document.querySelectorAll('.discovereedKeywords').length; i++) {
  var node = document.getElementsByClassName('discovereedKeywords')[i];
  node.innerHTML = node.innerHTML.replace(/,/g, '#');
}
```

---

Or [if you want to use jQuery](https://jsfiddle.net/fsk7jx7n/1/)

EDIT: [A. Wolff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37070056/1150683) is right in pointing out that in jQuery you do not need individually loop each item, as it internally does that anyway with the class selector.

```
$(".discovereedKeywords").each(function(i, e) {
  $(e).text(function() {
    return $(e).text().replace(/,/g, '#');
  });
});
```